# Why does VACUUM FULL ANALYZE not update pg_stat_user_tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Why does running `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` not update the `last_vacuum` column in `pg_stat_user_tables` in Postgres?

I have a moderately large database that requires some custom vacuuming and analyze procedures so those routines don't interfere with production performance. Therefore I scheduling a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` to be run at certain "safe" periods. Previously, I was just running `VACUUM FULL`, but this wasn't updating table statistics and was slowing down some queries, so I added `ANALYZE`, and that fixed the performance issues.

However, I noticed something strange. I already had a monitor setup to alert me for when vacuum hadn't been run in a while, just in case someone changes some config that stops the cronjob from running, and after I added `ANALYZE`, it started alerting me that vacuum was no longer being run.

Why is this?

There's nothing in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html) that says analyze disables vacuuming.

> "VACUUM ANALYZE performs a VACUUM and then an ANALYZE for each selected table."

> "VACUUM FULL rewrites the entire contents of the table into a new disk file with no extra space, allowing unused space to be returned to the operating system."

Granted, there's not explicit mention of what the expected behavior should be when `FULL` and `ANALYZE` are used together with `VACUUM`.

I have a lot of inserts and deletions, so I want `VACUUM FULL` to physically remove all dead tuples. I also want all table statistics to be updated.

Do I need to run `FULL` and `ANALYZE` separately?

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` performs both a `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`, though the "`VACUUM`" is more a side-effect of the `VACUUM FULL` table rewrite.  As such, one does not need to run `VACUUM FULL` and `ANALYZE` separately, if both are desired.

Whereas `VACUUM FULL` effectively performs a `VACUUM` by eliminating dead tuples, `VACUUM FULL` rewrites the table along the lines of a `CLUSTER` or some `ALTER TABLE`s.  Given that `last_vacuum` is intended to indicate the last time dead tuples were eliminated, as opposed to when the table was "created," some have argued that `last_vacuum` should not be updated following a `VACUUM FULL`.

Following PostgreSQL "bug" #5722 ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201010251242.o9PCgO10001534%40wwwmaster.postgresql.org)), during which Tom Lane chimed in, documentation was clarified to describe this behavior: see [PostgreSQL: Statistics Collector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html), which describes that `last_vacuum` as the "Last time at which this table was manually vacuumed (not counting VACUUM FULL)").  Likewise, `vacuum_count` is not incremented following a `VACUUM FULL`.

*If `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s are regularly and proportionally being performed on your table(s), `VACUUM FULL`s shouldn't be necessary.  Alternatively, consider letting the `VACUUM`s reclaim dead tuples for reuse by subsequent `INSERT`s (`UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s create dead tuples).  `VACUUM FULL` is costly in many ways, not to mention requiring of an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock not required by the non-`FULL` `VACUUM` variety.*